# Extending continuous functions from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology

**Definitions:**

Let $E$ be a subset of $X$. By an extension of a function $f: E \to \mathbb R$, I mean a function $\bar f: X \to \mathbb R$ such that $f = \bar f$ on $E$.

> **Question:** For every continuous function $f: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$, does there exist an extension $\bar f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is continuous at each $q \in \mathbb Q$?

In other words, can every continuous function on the rationals be extended to a function on the reals that is continuous at every rational point?

Comment: Just pick a rational function with an irrational zero in the denominator and no rational zero in the denominator, like $f(x) = 1/(x^2-2)$.

Comment: This would still be continuous on each $q \in \mathbb Q$ though.

Comment: Okay, I misread the question. Please consider rewriting it to be clearer both about what you're asking and what you're not asking, and perhaps what your motivation is.

Comment: Sorry, which part was unclear? I will edit it.

Comment: Maybe instead of saying "there is no extension... that is continuous on all of $\mathbf Q$" you could say "every extension ... is discontinuous at some rational number."  That's equivalent and I think it would be less likely to be misunderstood. It also would help if you include some motivation for your question.

Comment: @KConrad I agree with OP that the question is very clearly asked (I guess I'm usually quite fussy). [Nevertheless, for my own taste, I'd have asked in the positive: does every continuous function extend to one that is continuous at all rational points.]

Comment: I’ll change it to @YCor’s suggestion. It feels like in math there is often a disconnect between being clear and being human readable. Maybe I’ll add both.

Comment: Your update has an error: you don't want to declare the extension to the reals to be *continuous* there, since that would make it automatically continuous on the subset $\mathbf Q$.  I still think it would be nice to know what your motivation is (or just random curiosity?).

Comment: Oh, so this is a “toy case” of the following problem: if a function is continuous on a full measure set, does it agree a.e. with a function that is continuous a.e.? The motivation for *this* problem being... idle curiosity...

Comment: For a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, the set of those ponts where $f$ is discontinuous is the countable union of closed sets.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may extend by upper limit.

Details.

Denote $g(y)=\limsup_{x\to y, x\in \mathbb{Q}} f(x)$ for all real $y$. So, possibly $g$ takes the value $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ at some points. But we have $g(x)=f(x)$ for rational $x$, and for each rational $x$ and each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|g(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|y-x|<\delta$, in particular $g(y)\ne \pm \infty$ if $|y-x|<\delta$. Thus if we replace all infinite values of $g$ to 0, $g$ remains continuous at rational points.

Comment: Wow this just works huh.. I suppose this same proof would work if we replaced $\mathbb Q$ with any dense subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @NateRiver yes of course, and also with $\mathbf{R}$ (at the origin) replaced with any topological space.

Comment: @YCor what about arbitrary subset of arbitrary topological space? For arbitrary subset of reals the construction may be easily modified.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I said arbitrary dense subset of arbitrary topological space. For arbitrary subset some additional argument seems needed.

Comment: It could be harder for a non dense subset.. that’s interesting.. @FedorPetrov

Comment: ah, I am afraid that in the non-normal spaces the general counterexample  to Tietze extension theorem is still a counterexampe, like this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143072/166817

Comment: And the target space can be assumed to be an arbitrary locally compact space (replacing limsup with an arbitrary cluster point, and an arbitrary point when none). But this is not optimal, since it then follows that it works when the target space is an arbitrary closed subset of an arbitrary product of locally compact spaces.