# Maximally continuous extension of continuous functions from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function.

An *extension* of $f$ is a function $\tilde f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $\tilde f = f$ on $\mathbb Q$.

We say an extension $\tilde f$ of $f$ is *maximally continuous* if for any other extension $g$ of $f$, we have that if $g$ is continuous at $x \in \mathbb R$, then so is $\tilde f$.

> **Question:** For any continuous function $f: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$, does there exist a maximally continuous extension of $f$?

**Remark:** One can always obtain an extension that is continuous at every point in $\mathbb Q$, see for example, the answer in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394565/extending-continuous-functions-from-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-r) by Fedor Petrov.

Comment: Can't you apply Zorn's lemma to the pairs $(A,g)$, where $\mathbb{Q}\subset A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is an extension of $f$ continuous on $A$?

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be a natural choice of an upper bound though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There even exists a largest set $X$ to which $f$ can be continuously extended.

The trick is the following result (which I state here in more generality, to point out which topological assumptions one needs):

**Theorem.** Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, where $Y$ is $T_3$, and let $D \subseteq X$ be dense. Let $f: D \to Y$ be continuous and assume that the following property is satisfied for each point $x \in X \setminus D$ (equivalently, each point $x \in X$):

$(*)$ There exists $y_x \in Y$ such that, for each net $(x_j)$ in $D$ that converges to $x$, the net $(f(x_j))$ converges to $y_j$.

Then $f$ has a (obviously, unique) continuous extension to $X$.

(I gave a proof of this in a topology course a year ago, but unfortunately I don't know a reference - maybe somebody else can help out with a reference?)

**Application to your situation.** For $D = \mathbb{Q}$, let $X$ be the set of all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy property $(*)$. Then $f$ can be continuously extended to $X$, and this extension is clearly the largest one.

Comment: Ah, so it holds in more generality as well. Great answer, thanks!

Comment: To answer OP's question, we also need to know that if $f$ has a continuous extension to $X\subset\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ has an extension to $\mathbb{R}$ that is continuous on $X$. This is true, but was not completely obvious to me.

Comment: @JulianRosen: Good point! When writing the answer, I was a little bit too much focussed on "finding a continuous extension of $f$ to a domain as large as possible", and forgot to take into account that the question is framed somewhat differently.

Comment: You probably want to say that $f$ has a _continuous_ extension to $X$!

Comment: @DirkWerner: Oops. Yes, sure. Thank you for your correction!